# @font-face font working fine locally but when pushed to server it just shows up as a default HTML font

Tags: html, css, fonts

**UPDATE: FIXED, SEE BELOW**

Turns out the server I had the font name as 'Close.otf' in my fonts folder and 'close.otf' in my code, I'm guessing my code worked fine locally because it isn't case sensitive, GitHub's server is though apparentely. Just fixed by changing the C from uppercase to lowercase, now the font shows up fine.

**...**

I am building a website, and for the header I am using a custom font named "close.otf". Now, before pushing my changes to my GitHub Pages repo, I edit my css and html files locally.

So I added the custom font using the @font-face rule on my local CSS file, opened that file up with Chrome, and it shows up completely fine, as you can see:

[image: The font in question is the one used in the Harry Escott header]

However, upon pushing the CSS file and HTML file to the GitHub server where my site is hosted, for some reason, upon loading the site in Chrome, the font shows up as follows:

[image]

Here is the code I used:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family:"close";
    src: url("../fonts/close.otf") format("opentype");
}
```

And yes, since the local files are a clone of the GitHub repo, it's not some simple mistake like making sure it's in the same folder as the adress etc.

It's also worth noting all other custom fonts I've added to the site have worked completely fine, like the one below the header used in the nav links.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you used the developer tools in your browser to see what the server is sending? Your browser is requesting a font file, but the server may be returning forbidden, not found or some other error that will help you troubleshoot.

Comment: Just checked now, seeing a 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404', then it shows the exact font I mentioned in the code. Checked my fonts folder, realized the C in closed.otf was uppercase and in my code it was in lowercase. I'm guessing locally the code isn't case sensitive, but GitHub's server is. Just changed the c to lowercase, all working now. Thanks!